# How to create a new column based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame `df`:

```
col1  col2
1     C
1     B
1     A
2     C
2     C
3     A
3     C
3     B
```

I need to create a new column `col3` and assign `T` or `F` per each unique `col1`: for each unique `col1`, if at least one row is equal to `A` in `col2`, then `col3` is equal to `T`. Otherwise, it's equal to `F`.

Expected result:

```
col1  col2  col3
1     C     T
1     B     T
1     A     T
2     C     F
2     C     F
3     A     T
3     C     T
3     B     T
```

How can I do so? I tried to use `apply(lambda ...)` solution, but it goes rowwise and assigns T only when `col1` is 1 (basically because the last row for 1 is equal to A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `numpy`'s `where` function like this:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> df['col3'] = np.where(df['col1'].isin(df[df['col2']=='A']['col1'].unique()), 'T', 'F')
>> print(df)
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    C    T
1     1    B    T
2     1    A    T
3     2    C    F
4     2    C    F
5     3    A    T
6     3    C    T
7     3    B    T
```

Comment: do we need to use `unique()` as we taking strict comparison based on `df['col1'].isin(df[df['col2']=='A']` hence  i believe simply `np.where(df['col1'].isin(df[df['col2']=='A']['col1']), 'T', 'F')`  do work.

Answer (score 2):

Check `groupby` with `transform`

```
df['col2'].eq('A').groupby(df['col1']).transform('any')
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: col2, dtype: bool

df['col3']=df['col2'].eq('A').groupby(df['col1']).transform('any').map({True:'T', False:'F'})
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I create a new column with "T" and "F" values? I do not need True and False.

Comment: Perfect. One quick clarification. How should I change `eq("A")` if the condition is "equal to A or B". I tried `.eq("A" or "B")`, but it gave me wrong results.

Comment: @Fluxy `.isin(['A','B'])`

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution you can choose with converting int to `str` with `astype('str')` with `str.contains`:

```
>>> df.assign(col3=df['col1'].astype(str).str.contains('1|3').map({True:'T', False:'F'}))
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    C    T
1     1    B    T
2     1    A    T
3     2    C    F
4     2    C    F
5     3    A    T
6     3    C    T
7     3    B    T
```